# Android development

Tags: android

I plan to work with android. Please point me some good books and blogs/discussion/tutorials/ forums for getting vast and in depth knowledge quickly about this android technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted some useful links [here](http://primalpop.wordpress.com/2010/05/26/first-few-steps-in-android/)